# preventDefault() with drop-down-menu + prevDef disable after second click - explanation?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, preventdefault

Thanks to MjrKusanagi we replace preventDefault with return false.

Also thanks to him we refactored the code to smaller size.

## HTML

```
<ul id="menu-top-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">1 level</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com"> 2 level</a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">3 level</a></li>
                </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">1 level</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">2 level</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

as You see normal nested menu

### jQuery

```
$('#menu-top-menu li').click(function(event) {
if($(this).children('ul').is(':visible')) return true;
if($(this).children().is('a:last-child')) return true;
if($(this).siblings().is(":visible")) $(this).siblings().children("ul").hide("fast");
$(this).children('ul').toggle("slow");
return false;
```

Code works great. You can easily implement it to any drop-down-menu ;)
Thank You MjrKusanagi !!!

http://jsfiddle.net/NLKmb/20/

Comment: The question is a bit confusing without having the complete jQuery code.

Comment: Sorry for that. Question 1. Why "preventDefault is off" on second click? (which is great for me to create mobile drop-down-menu) Question 2. How to kill preventDefault for last child/last level of each parent menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can replace all the code you had in the JSFiddle with the following:

```
$('#menu-top-menu li').click(function(ev) {
    if($(this).children('ul').is(':visible'))
        return true;
    if($(this).children('ul').toggle("slow").length)
        return false;
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replay. Yes, I know. I think that I didn't explain what is my question exactly. I need mobile version for drop-down-menu and I can't use :hover on mobile devices. I cann't understand why preventDefault works on this code and don't work on second click ;]

Comment: That's because the default action when you click any link anchor `a` is to go to that URL. If you don't want that behavior, you need to prevent it, or `return false;`. More precisely, it is working, but it immediately reloads the page and returns to the default state.

Comment: I can replace it but links doesn't works. Scenario: You clicinkg menu one time and it's toggling, You clicking second time and it's sending You to other site. What is the purpose of having drop-down-menu for only droping-down ? ;)

Comment: I think I finally understand what you're looking for. The JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/NLKmb/27/.